# #if PreProcessor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C#/Asp.net World, Recently I came across the #if DEBUG PreProcessor but even after looking at the posts on Stack Over flow and MSDN Website and other blogs as well I am not able To make it Work.

I am Making a small Website.
I am implementing a DataLayer by Adding A new Project To The Solution.
In The Datalayer I am checking the Parameters passed to the Stored Procedure.

So The Aim is to print the Parameters Passed when The Application is running in Debug Mode and When The application is Running in Release Mode it Should not Show the Parameters.

any Help Shall Be Appreciated.

Thanks

```
#define DEBUG

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TestWebsite.DataLayer.BussinessObjects;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace TestWebsite.DataLayer  
{  
    public class StatesManager  
    {   
        public ICollection<States> getAll(States statesObj)  
        {  
            List<object> parameters = new List<object>();  
            List<States> scol = new List<States>();  
            try  
            {  
                parameters.Add(statesObj.State);
                parameters.Add(statesObj.Abbreviation);
                parameters.Add(statesObj.StartRowIndex);
                parameters.Add(statesObj.MaximumRowsCount);
                parameters.Add(statesObj.SortExpression);
                parameters.Add(statesObj.SortDirection);

#if DEBUG
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("State =" + statesObj.State + ",<br/>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Abbreviation =" + statesObj.Abbreviation + ",<br/>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("StartRowIndex =" + statesObj.StartRowIndex.ToString() + ",<br/>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("MaximumRowsCount =" + statesObj.MaximumRowsCount.ToString() + ",<br/>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("SortExpression =" + statesObj.SortExpression + ",<br/>");
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("SortDirection =" + statesObj.SortDirection.ToString() + "<br/>");
#endif

                object[] paramArray = parameters.ToArray();

                SqlDatabase db = new SqlDatabase(ConnectionManager.ConnectionString);
                DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetAllStates", paramArray);
                IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    States sreader = new States();
                    sreader.State = (string)reader[reader.GetOrdinal("State")];
                    sreader.Abbreviation = (string)reader[reader.GetOrdinal("Abbreviation")];
                    sreader.IsActive = (bool)reader[reader.GetOrdinal("IsActive")];
                    sreader.RowNumber = (long)reader[reader.GetOrdinal("RowNo")];
                    sreader.StateID = (int)reader[reader.GetOrdinal("StateID")];

                    scol.Add(sreader);
                    sreader = null;
                }
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally { parameters = null; }
            return scol;
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code, particularly the preprocessor snippet.

Comment: Show us some code so that we can see what's "not working."

Comment: Is your Shift key a little bipolar today from all that C# coding?

Comment: I am comletely Newbie regarding The Preprocessor and Build/Release stuff; So stuff Like Step1,.. Step2 , ....  like approach or some pointer( some blog or link) will be very helpful.    Thanks Again In Advance

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to use `#if` in an ASPX page.

The preprocessor is only supported in C# source.

Instead, you can use a normal `if`:

```
<% if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

This property reflects the presence of `<compilation debug="true">` in Web.config.

You may be able to write

```
<%
#if DEBUG %>
   ...
<%
#endif%>
```

(note newlines), but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Thanks for The Valuable Syntax: HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled; but I am Trying to do that in c sharp file just Trying to Do Response.Write For The Parameters When The Website is in Debug Mode with The Help Of Preprocessors

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in solution explorer, click Properties.
Go to the Build tab and select your Debug configuration from the dropdown.
Ensure that the "Define DEBUG Constant" is checked.

Do the same thing for the Release configuration, but make sure that the "Define DEBUG Constant" is unchecked.

This will ensure that all

```
#if DEBUG
```

directives work as you are expecting.

**EDIT:**
Since you are using a web SITE project, go into your web.config file, under the system.web section and locate or add a <compilation debug="false" /> node.  This attribute will turn the DEBUG constant on and off.

Comment: Hi Steve, When I Right click The Project from Solution Explorer go to Properties I do not see Define Debug Constant or other Things You say In The Post above? I am using ASP.net3.5 and developing WebSite Project

Comment: Hi shankbond, see my edit for how to enable and disable this setting in a web SITE project.

Comment: Steve, Do You mean <compilation debug="true">; if that is the case then I tried doing that but of no help.

Comment: Yes, I guess I didn't type that part out...oops.  That is what should do it.  I'm not sure what the issue is then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `#if` in your ASP.NET markup. If you use code behind, you can do the following in your markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="DebugOutput" EnableViewstate="false" Visible="false">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="OutputValue" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

And in your code behind:

```
#if DEBUG
    DebugOutput.Visible = true;
    OutputValue.Text = "My output string";
#endif
```

You could use a panel instead of a placeholder, but panels have a control state, even when viewstate is disabled, therefore you will get entries in viewstate for that panel even in release code.

Comment: Hi Residuum, Though I am not using the preprocessor in the markUp, but Your Advice will sure come handy whenever I need To That in MarkUp.  Actually I am Trying to that in Csharp file Itself, as shown in the sample I provide.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax wise this is what the "if" block should look like.

```
#if DEBUG
// do something that is debugish
#endif
```

In order for this statement to work DEBUG has to be "defined" you can do this in code (not the best way)...

```
#define DEBUG
```

Or you can do this in your IDE by double clicking on the "Properties" under the project and then going to the "Compile" tab. Make sure that you see the "Define DEBUG constant" checked.

As an alternative to your solution you might consider using a [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) instead of the DEBUG constant.

[How to: Use TraceSource and Filters with Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your edited question:

You're trying to write to the output in the middle of the codebehind, before the response is set up.

You can't do that.

You need to pass the information to the ASPX view and write it there, or use actual debugging features such as trace.

Comment: Can You Please elaborate more; I am using Asp.net Website project, and I have done that(Response.Write) several times and have never encountered the "before the response is set up" issue.

Comment: Hi SLaks Thanks for the quick Response; I am simply Adding a data Layer Which is just a Class Library The DataLayer is being Called by Bussiness Layer Which is Again a class Library, Now I am adding the reference of the Bussines Layer To My Website. And Calling The Code from The Code Behind of The aspx Page